# jqGrid on data populate event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have been lurking around jqGrid documentation but am unable to find any thing like "ondatapopulate" event. Actually I want to add custom formatting to rows of jqGrid but i cannot do so before rows are populated. I need to bind to an event which fires when all the rows are loaded.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Do you tried to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)? It's very simple to use and it will be called on building of HTML fragment of the cell *during* filling of the grid. It will be helpful if you write an example which kind of formatting you need to implement.

Comment: I did no try custom formatter. All i wanted was to highlight a particular column upon clicking on the column header or if ajax call returns a particular flag. The answer below worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at the `gridComplete` event, although you may also want to have a look at `loadComplete`. From the [Events page of the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents):

> - `gridComplete` - This fires after all the data is loaded into the grid and all other processes are complete. Also the event fires independent from the datatype parameter and after sorting paging and etc.
> - `loadComplete` - This event is executed immediately after every server request.

Comment: I know it's three years later, but thank you I actually needed gridComplete :)

Comment: @ArlaudPierre - No problem, glad it helped you out.